::http__getUrl Fail to parse [Line: 1, Column: 1]
I have a string var $message that contains the chars "åæø" and the system encoding is cp1252.
But when i try to do a getUrl it i get fail to parse from the http::getUrl
I did a
binary scan $message H* hex
The the åæø returns hex e5e6f8 but it should be c3a5c3a6c3b8.
[::http::geturl $url  -query $message]


The -query parameter is supposed to be passed a string encoded using ::http::formatQuery. Have you done that? (While we're at it, Tcl internally operates on strings using Unicode no matter what legacy code page Windows uses on your system; the latter comes into consideration only when you need to explicitly decode stuff going from the outside etc).

Inside Tcl, your string is always a Unicode string. The system encoding used to pass filenames to the OS and to initialize the encoding used to read and write text files (though you can override that). HTTP does not use the system encoding by default at all; the protocol specifies the encoding (e.g., %-encoded UTF-8 for query strings these days). The http package's getUrl command requires you to pre-convert the query and provides formatQuery to do that. (There are scenarios where you don't want to encode the query, but this isn't one.)
Binary data in Tcl is just a string that uses the lowest 256 Unicode characters, and binary scan internally converts out-of-range characters by masking off the high bits of each value. (scan %c handles the whole range.) You could apply binary scan to the output of encoding convertto utf-8... but formatQuery should be doing that for you.
